# Spring Constructor Injection Weird Error

Tags: spring

I have encountered below BeanDefinitionDecorator error at below constructor-arg dependency line in Bean XML (root-context.xml) in Eclipse, but no issue when using setter injection with property element, appreciate if anyone here could provide advice, as not able to identify the root cause even after search through Internet.  Thanks in advance.

**Error encountered**

"Multiple annotations found at this line:

- Cannot locate BeanDefinitionDecorator for element [constructor-arg]
- cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'constructor-arg'.
- Configuration problem: Cannot locate BeanDefinitionDecorator for element [constructor-arg] Offending resource: file [C:/Users/Administrator/
  workspace/EsmProject/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]"

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

        <beans:bean id="myObject" class="com.packapp.MyObject"></beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="homeDAO" class="com.packapp.HomeDAOImpl">
           <constructor-arg><ref bean="myObject"/></constructor-arg>
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id = "homeService" class="com.packapp.HomeServiceImpl">
           <beans:property name="homeDAO" ref="homeDAO"></beans:property>
        </beans:bean>

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.packapp" />
    </beans:beans>
```

---

```
public class MyObject {
    private String homeName;
    private String homeAddress;

    public String getHomeName(){
        return homeName;
    }
    public void setHomeName(String homeName){
        this.homeName = homeName;
    }
    public String getHomeAddress(){
        return homeAddress;
    }
    public void setHomeAddress(String homeAddress){
        this.homeAddress = homeAddress;
    }
}
```

---

```
@Repository
public class HomeDAOImpl implements HomeDAO {
    private MyObject obj;
    public HomeDAOImpl(MyObject obj){
        this.obj = obj;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return this.obj.getHomeAddress();

    }
}
```

---

```
@Service
public class HomeServiceImpl implements HomeService {
    private HomeDAO homeDAO;
    public void setHomeDAO(HomeDAO homeDAO){
        this.homeDAO = homeDAO;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return this.homeDAO.getAddress();
    }
```

### }

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("ctrl2")
public class HomeController2 {
    private HomeService homeService;

    @Autowired(required=true)
    @Qualifier(value="homeService")
    public void setHomeService (HomeService hs){
        this.homeService = hs;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/site2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate + this.homeService.getAddress());

        return "home2";
    }
}
```

Comment: No it isn't a weird exception, you have another root namespace. You have bound the `beans` namespace to use, so prefix `constructor-arg` with `beans:` just like the `property` and `bean` element.

Comment: @M. Deinum, Thanks, after changed to beans, still encountered error, i.e. "Multiple annotations found at this line.  Cannot locate BeanDefinitionParser for element [ref]. cvc-complex-type.2.4.c. The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'ref'."

Comment: The sample applies for the `ref` element. It applies to all elements that would occur in the `spring-beans.xsd`. However instead of using the `ref` element, just add it as an attribute to the `constructor-arg`. `<beans constructor-arg ref="myObject" />` easier to read and less xml.

Comment: Thanks M. Deinum, Solved, but turned to BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.packapp.HomeDAOImpl]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.packapp.HomeDAOImpl.<init>(), eventhough I have declared the constructor in class as shown in question.

Comment: Because you also have `@Repository`, which means component scanning will detect the bean. Due to the lack of `@Autowired` on the constructor it expects a default constructor. You basically have 2 instances. Either remove the xml configuration and add `@Autowired` to the constructor, or remove component-scanning.

Comment: I have removed component scanning, add controller bean, either with or without @Autowired for constructor, still get NoSuchMethodException: HomeDAOImpl.<init>.  Can repository or HomeDaoImpl implement HomeDao interface as shown above trigger it?

Comment: What is your bean definition looking like? Are you still using the `constructor-ref`?

Comment: I solved it now after removed the component scan

Comment: Solved it after removed additional component scan from servlet1 and servlet 2 context. Also define controller bean in servlet 2 which call above service and DAO bean in application context. Also autowire controller setter method with service bean, while service and DAO bean dependency declared in application context.  Now got NullPointerException in below controller code, get model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate + this.homeService.getAddress())

Comment: Actually my controller code stated question, was tested fine previously, until I changed to constructor for the service bean.  It error out at model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate + this.homeService.getAddress()).  Suspect the HomeService bean null??

Comment: Because the removal of `<context:component-scan />` also disable annotation driven configuration. Either fix the components to work properly with component-scanning (add `@Autowired` to the constructors and remove the service and ao from the xml configuration) or add `<context:annotation-config />`. I strongly suggest a read of the reference guide as you seem to be missing some of the basic understanding.

Comment: M. Denium, Thanks a lotfor  your speedy & helpful advice.  Solved it using manual dependency config in servlet context xml which wire controller bean with service bean, for both constructor & setter injection method.

Comment: M. Deinum, One more question, understand setter injection is used for optional dependency.  Is that mean we can define the setter injection dependency method in class file, but not define the setter method with property element in Bean XML, thus can cause program error if the particular dependency or object required at run time, while constructor injection always requires configuration in XML, else throw compilation error ?  Thanks again

Comment: No. constructor injection doesn't require xml configuration, it can be auto detected (if `@Autowired` is placed correctly) or with java config.

Comment: Noted.  So, am I correct  that setter injection mean it is optional to define the setter method with property element in XML config, thus optional dependency ?  Appreciate your advice, as I can't find through internet that explain in detailed.  Thanks.

Comment: Perharp let me rephrase, setter method is optional dependency because it is optional to call the setter method (i.e. XML file, java config and autowired), while we must call constructor method (either XML file, java config and autowired), is my understanding correct ?

Comment: Yes and this is also generally advised to use constructors for mandatory dependencies, that way you cannot construct an object in an invalid state.

Answer (score 3):

I think `<constructor-arg><ref bean="myObject"/></constructor-arg>`

must be `<beans:constructor-arg><beans:ref bean="myObject"/></beans:constructor-arg>`

because you have a prefix for elements in `spring-beans.xsd`.

Comment: @Leanne can you add this as an update to your question please?

Comment: Thanks for your response.   Added into my question.  So far still encountered the error, eventhough it is just a simple dependency setting. =(.  Need expert here for help.

Comment: @Leanne see my updated answer. you also need `beans:` before `ref`.

Comment: Solved with <beans:constructor-arg ref="myObject" />.  But got different error now, i.e. BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.packapp.HomeDAOImpl]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.packapp.HomeDAOImpl.<init>(), eventhough I have declared the constructor in class as shown in question.

Comment: @Leanne Your class is annotated as `@Repository`, so you need a no arg constructor. or add an `@Autowired` annotation to your constructor `public HomeDAOImpl(MyObject obj){`

Comment: Jens, I tried by removing component scanning, add controller bean, either with or without @Autowired for constructor, still get NoSuchMethodException: HomeDAOImpl.<init>.  Can repository or HomeDaoImpl implement HomeDao interface as shown above trigger it?

Comment: @Leanne yes it can/it should implment the interface.

Comment: Solved it after removed additional component scan from servlet1 and servlet 2 context. Also define controller bean in servlet 2 which call above service and DAO bean in application context. Also autowire controller setter method with service bean, while service and DAO bean dependency declared in application context.  Now got NullPointerException in below controller code, get model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate + this.homeService.getAddress())